# How to test the google +1 button local

Tags: google-plus

I am just creating an html file to test out the google +1 button. I guess the problem my html is not deployed on a server. How can you test the google+1 button on your local machine. This code doesn't render anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Google+1</title>

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" /> -->
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js”></script>
</head>

<body >

<g:plusone></g:plusone>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it can't be done because Google's API check the source of the request, otherwise many security holes would be exist.

Why won't you check it online? Just upload the site to it's domain and try to +1 from your account.

Another option for design purposes only: download an image of the +1 button and use it in the offline version.

Comment: Thanks. I am creating a site and would like to design it with twitter, google+ and facebook. I am currently just needing this for the design.

Comment: You can download an image of the +1 button for that purpose if it's so important to you :) I actually added this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably just opening the HTML file locally. You can run the Google+ widgets on your local machine and will need to have internet access to load the external scripts. What you need to do is start up a web server and open the file from there.  This is due to permissions for JavaScript required from the +1 code.

If you are on a Mac, you can do this either through the built-in Apache server (copy the file to /Library/WebServer/Documents and navigate to localhost/filename.html) or by spinning up a Python web server in the same folder as the file with the following command:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

After starting the Python web server, you can navigate to localhost port 8000.

If you are running on a Windows PC, you can find a number of web servers and install them, [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) is a pretty simple option. Again, you would just install WAMP and then put your HTML file in the web/www folder that WAMP created and navigate there from localhost. You can also install Python and use the built-in web server as mentioned before.